# StepRequest with StepRequest.STEP_MIN parameter

Tags: java, debugging, jdi, jpda

In Java Debug Interface, What does StepRequest with StepRequest.STEP_MIN parameter mean ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/StepRequest.html Java Docs says "Step to the next available location". What is next available location ? I understand StepRequest.STEP_LINE parameter to run line by line but what is StepRequest.STEP_MIN parameter ?  When I ran with this parameter there are multiple step requests for a single line, and I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RequestManager javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html#createStepRequest(com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20int,%20int)):

> A sizevalue of StepRequest.STEP_MIN will generate a step event each
>   time the code index changes. It represents the smallest step size
>   available and often maps to the instruction level. A size value of
>   StepRequest.STEP_LINE will generate a step event each time the source
>   line changes unless line number information is not available, in which
>   case a STEP_MIN will be done instead

Looking at [The class file format#The LineNumberTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12)

> The LineNumberTable attribute is an optional variable-length attribute
>   in the attributes table of a Code (§4.7.3) attribute. *It may be used
>   by debuggers to determine which part of the Java Virtual Machine code
>   array corresponds to a given line number* in the original source file.

Probably a StepRequest use code-array and line-number-table to determine the next step location.

Comment: It will be good if you could explain for a single line with code "i=30;j=i;" how many times step event will be generated if I use STEP_MIN. Is it possible to execute that statement in two pass, one for each expression ?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry about that.
My original intent was to add a code sample, but last time I use JDI was more than 18 months ago and I need time to collect all tools to give a correct example

Comment: I see  you have worked in this field for a good amount of time. Can you tell me some useful groups,forems where I can ask questions on this topic, stackoverflow looks idle on this topic. AFAIK only way is to execute each and every method to understand it because java docs are not much helpful , neither there are much resources on internet for this topic.

Comment: My starting point was https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/examples.html. I downloaded and watch code of all examples in that page; also I googled for jpda, java stratum, java debugging etc.
I did exactly what you are doing now: searching stuff, reading, debugging code and try by myself!